# Is there any problem with computing the whole program in an ISR?

Tags: embedded, stm32, microcontroller, isr

I have a program that should be run periodically on a MCU (ex. STM32). For example it should be run at every 1 ms. If I program an 1ms ISR and call my complete program in it, assuming it will not exceed 1ms, is that a good way? Is there any problem that I could be facing? Will it be precise?

Comment: What Miro said, but you will have to be able to recognise when your system has outgrown such a simple solution, or when the system you need to build is not suited to such a solution.

Answer (score 6):

The usual answer would be probably that ISRs should be generally kept to a minimum and most of the work should be performed in the "background loop". (Since you are apparently using the traditional ["foreground-background" architecture, a.k.a. "main+ISRs"](https://youtu.be/AoLLKbvEY8Q)).

But ARM Cortex-M (e.g., STM32) has been specifically designed such that ISRs *can* be [written as plain C functions](https://youtu.be/O0Z1D6p7J5A). In that case, working with ISRs is no different than working with any other C code. This includes ease of debugging.

Moreover, ARM Cortex-M comes with the NVIC (Nested Vectored Interrupt Controller). The NVIC allows you to [prioritize interrupts](https://www.state-machine.com/cutting-through-the-confusion-with-arm-cortex-m-interrupt-priorities) and they can preempt each other. This means that you can quite easily build sets of periodic "tasks" (ISRs), which run under the preemptive, priority-based scheduler. Interestingly, this scheduler (implemented in the NVIC hardware) meets all requirements of [RMA/RMS (Rate Monotonic Analysis/Scheduling)](https://youtu.be/kLxxXNCrY60), so you could prove the schedulability of your system. Of course, the ISR "tasks" *cannot block* internally, but this is *not* required for RMA/RMS. Also, if you have any shared resources between ISRs running at different priorities (or ISR and the background loop), you need to properly protect the resources by disabling interrupts.

So, your idea of using ISRs as "tasks" makes a lot of sense to me. Your system will be optimal meaning that any other approach would be less efficient. (This includes the use of any kind of RTOS.) Also, this design can be low-power because you could use the "background loop" in main() to put your CPU and peripherals into low-power sleep mode (WFI instruction, etc.) In fact, you can view the "background loop" as the idle "task" in this "hardware-RTOS".

Comment: Good summary. As an addition to the last paragraph, Cortex-M has a SLEEPONEXIT bit, which when set means it automatically sleeps when there is no ISR running. So you maybe don't even need an idle task to handle hat.